# How to create a NSWindow like iTunes mini player (always on top but get no focus!)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I have a borderless window with a webview in it, which is always on top.
I want to create a NSWindow which is:

1. Always on top
2. **Does not** take the focus from the current foreground app
3. **Does** enable user mouse interaction (without forcing the user to switch focus to it - aka "click on it twice")

The problem I have atm is that to interact with the window (e.g. see hover effect, or click a link in the webview), the user has to click the window (which gives it focus) and only then the hover effect shows.

How can I make a window like iTunes mini player which doesn't take the focus from the current app - but also interacts with mouse? (see screenshots below)

Thanks!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems - (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent  does half of what I want, the other half is also accepting "mouse move events" when the window is inactive. (because I want to have a hover effect, like the mini player does)

Answer (score 0):

To receive `mouseEntered:`, `mouseMoved:` and `mouseExited:` events even when your app is not active, you must add a tracking area to some view in your window and set the tracking area's properties accordingly.

Take a look at [NSTrackingArea](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/index.html).

You'll probably want to add a tracking area with the options `NSTrackingActiveAlways` and `NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited`.

Comment: I did that, but then I tried to pass along the events to the webview, and that didn't work - so it didn't show hover effects (caused by mouse move event)

Comment: Then your problem is in how you're trying to pass along the events. Why don't you handle the events natively and just have a callback in your web content's javascript to show/hide the controls?

Comment: the web page is working fine if it is in focus. using css :hover - buttons appear and dissappear as I wish. but when the webview doesn't have focus - it does not receive mouse events - even if NSTrackingArea is installed.  the goal is now - I do i pass the events captures by the tracking area to the webview.

Comment: You can't, WebView just doesn't work like that. The solution is for you to install some javascript in your web content to show the hover effect and call that from your app. I'll put together a sample app later if I have the time ;)

Comment: As I explained before. No matter what java script you write - it won't receive any mouse hover events unless the NSWindow is Active! And as this question title clearly states - the NSWindow must be on top but not have focus (like the iTunes miniplayer). So please don't bother writing any javascript :)

Comment: The javascript doesn't have to receive any event! The javascript can be just a callback to make the hover effect happen. You receive the event in ObjC and just call the JS to make the hover effect happen.